# What tax code is used for tax refunds?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

For example, the W-2 Form for salary has a tax code of 460.
I can't seem to find the tax code for money returned from federal or state.

Does anyone know what code this is?
Is it different code for state and federal and if so, then at the very least what's the code for federal? I'll check my state's documentation.
[image]

When I'm using finance software it has some stuff preconfigured, such as "paycheck/wages" it's already set as 'taxable' and "code 460"

It's my understanding that next year, whatever money I received as a 'tax return' from federal and state is 'income' that i will have to pay taxes on next year. what code applies to that income? is it 460 because it came out of my paycheck to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean by "tax code of 460"? What's the context here?

Comment: "Tax Code 460" may relate to rules for long-term contracts. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: You probably also need to clarify "_money returned from federal or state_"... what sort of money returned for what sort of purpose? I could be wrong, but if it's a tax refund, I believe from other questions on PF&M that that doesn't need to be entered on tax returns (it's not _income_, it's a return of money that essentially shouldn't have been paid/taken in the first place).

Comment: what software are you using? that would be the place to start.

Comment: Did you click on the Big Blue Question Mark next to the Taxable field?

Comment: If you do not clarify, namely, state what software this question is about, the question is likely to be closed as unclear.

Comment: Clicking the question mark brings up the list that is shown in the picture. I was also under the impression that the software in question shouldn't matter, that these codes are something that IRS uses not the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am skipping the part of the question about the code related to refunds and will discuss refunds.

If the refund is for federal taxes, then there is no impact on your state or federal taxes the next year. The only exception is if you told the IRS not to send you your refund and instead asked them to apply it to the next years taxes. I don't think many people pick that option.

If the refund is for state taxes then it might have to be counted for income on your federal form. If you itemized on your 2017 taxes that you filed in April 2018, and your state sent you a refund in April 2018, then when you file in April 2019 you will have to determine if that refund will be considered taxable income by the IRS. The good news is that your state will send you a 1099-G (G as in government) in early 2019 reminding you about that income. There is a easy worksheet on the federal forms to determine if it is taxable income.

So check to see if the software you are using allows you to specify a 1099-G form. That will tell you the code.

Comment: That works for me. it's confusing, but i think i get it. the software does call it a "260" code. there is one for federal too but only if it's from unemployment, code 606. Thanks!